# Scope inheritance with ng-bind (not working) vs {{ }} (working)

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and just done with the scope inheritance. Following is the sample code I wrote. I am referencing angular version 1.5.0

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ScopeInheritanceParentController" class="scope_inheritance_parent">
    <span>Parent</span><br /><br />
    <!--<span ng-bind="title" /><br /><br />-->
    <span>{{title}}</span><br /><br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="title" /><br /><br />
    <div ng-controller="ScopeInheritanceChildController" class="scope_inheritance_child">
        <span>Child</span><br /><br />
        <!--<span ng-bind="title" /><br /><br />-->
        <span>{{title}}</span><br /><br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="title" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myapp.controllers')
    .controller('ScopeInheritanceParentController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Initial title set by Parent controller ctor function"
    }])
    .controller('ScopeInheritanceChildController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = 'Initial title set by Child controller ctor function'
    }])
```

So far so good and I get the output as:
[image]

**Issue**

When I comment `{{title}}` syntax and uncomment `ng-bind="title"` span I see the output as:
[image]

1. Where is Child controller now?
2. Why is it not displaying text box from Parent controller?

I know that `{{}}` syntax creates a watcher internally and thus angular is able to update view when expression changes. I also read that `ng-bind` is same as `{{}}`, so I would assume it works the same way.

Comment: Can you create a plunker/jsfiddle about this problem? Could even resolve your problem (the problem disappears in the demo). At least for me your code works as expected, no problems what so ever.

Comment: you need to close your span tag with a </span> (it is not self enclosing) see: http://plnkr.co/edit/yA2sN2OTCwOF5W5wcOB0?p=preview

Comment: @NitsanBaleli My bad. I should have realized ng-bind will `innerHTML` the value. (lips sealed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span tag has such syntax

```
<span ng-bind='title'></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I should not forget HTML whilst learning anything.